# scanf skipping lines in visual studio 2015

Tags: c

I'm unsure if the scan_f is causing my program to skip lines while it's being debugged. 
The first printf(""); runs and accepts and input, however the second one outputs but doesn't accept and input and jumps to the third printf(""); . I initial was using a getchar but as I'm unfamiliar with C I reverted back to scanf_s until I'm more familiar with it.

```
//libary 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

//global variables
float wPrice = 1.80, bPrice = 1.50, sPrice = 1.75, mPrice = 2.00, deliveryPrice = 2.00;

//define globalconstants

//define Poundsign

#define POUNDSIGN 156

//THe breadtype chars will be uppercase
char w, b, s, m, delivery;

//void main

void main() {

    //local variables
    float totalCost = 0.00;

    //prompt user for what breads they want?

        printf("Hello do you want Wholemeal bread?(Y/N): ");
        //w = getchar();
        scanf_s("%c", &w, 1);
        fflush(stdin);
        w = toupper(w);



    printf("\nDo you want Brown bread?(Y/N): ");
    scanf_s("%c", &b, 1);
    fflush(stdin);
    //b = getchar();
    b = toupper(b);


    printf("\nDo you want Seeded bread?(Y/N): ");
    scanf_s("%c", &s, 1);
    fflush(stdin);
    //s = getchar();
    s = toupper(s);


    printf("\nDo you want Multigrain bread?(Y/N): ");
    scanf_s("%c", &m, 1);
    fflush(stdin);
    //m = getchar();
    m = toupper(m);


    printf("\n Will you need the bread delivered?(Y/N)\nYOU MUST LIVE WITHIN 8 MILES OF THE BAKERY TO BE ELIGIBLE FOR DELIVERY:");
//delivery = getchar();
    scanf_s("%c", &delivery, 1);
    fflush(stdin);
    delivery = toupper(delivery);

    //work out price with if statment

    //wholegrain bread 
    if (w = 'Y') {

        totalCost = totalCost + wPrice;
    }

    //brown bread
    if (b = 'Y') {
        totalCost = totalCost + bPrice;
    }
    //seeded
    if (s = 'Y') {

        totalCost = totalCost + sPrice;

    }
    //multigrain
    if (m = 'Y') {
        totalCost = totalCost + mPrice;
    }

    if (delivery = 'Y') {
        totalCost = totalCost + deliveryPrice;
    }

    //if no bread has been purchased 

    else {

        printf("You have purchased no bread");
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }

    //print the total to them

    printf("Wholemeal bread cost %c%1.2f\nBrown bread costs %c%1.2f\nSeeded bread costs %c%1.2f\nMultigrain bread costs %c%1.2f", POUNDSIGN, wPrice, POUNDSIGN, bPrice, POUNDSIGN, sPrice, POUNDSIGN, mPrice); 
    //total price
    printf("\nYour total price including delivery is %c%1.2f", POUNDSIGN, totalCost);

    //hang system
    system("pause");
    exit(0);


}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: `w = 'Y'` : use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: This is gonna be a newline character left in buffer thing.  More dups than Jon Skeet has rep.  OP failure to search....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because grossly multi-dupped scanf(%c..) CR-left-in-buffer thingy.

Comment: Googling 'scanf skipping lines' gives: 'About 119,000 results', with SO Q&A taking the top 4 places.

Comment: @MartinJames true, but as a specific question it has also many other issues which have been addressed in the answers. Think of it this way, closing it means that this OP will very soon ask again *`if` is not working in c*! Which is also common.

Answer (score 2):

```
w = 'Y'
```

Thats not a comparison, but an assignment. Do

```
w == 'Y'
```

instead.

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Thats not allowed (undefined behaviour).

To skip whitespaces before scanf input, do

```
scanf(" %c", &char);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to programming so I'm working for class assignments.

Comment: @Lombax If this solved your problem, consider accepting iharob's answer, as his was first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ignore the trailing `'\n'` that is inserted into the buffer when you press <kbd>Return</kbd>. To do so try like this

```
scanf(" %c", &character);
/*     ^ this will skip all white spaces */
```

all other spcifiers skip them normally except `"%c"`.

Also:

1. Don't do this `fflush(stdin)`.
2. Your comparisons are assignments as @[BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216042/scanf-skipping-lines-in-visual-studio-2015/33216131#comment54236080_33216042) pointed out.

Also, you should care a lot about the code formatting and style. You might say that it doesn't affect how the code runs, and it's true. But it affects the overall quality and maintainability. You will have more bugs if your code is messy than if it is beautiful.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm new to do this so sorry about the mistakes.

Comment: If you are new to this, you should not be sorry. Instead learn and don't make the same mistakes again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line code above the program

**#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS**

**Example:**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

 int n;
 scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("value:%d \n",n);


 return 0;
}
```